# Date Comparison with two text boxes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am having two text boxes (startdate and enddate).
condition : startdate should be >=21 of this month
            end date sholud be <=20 of next month
how it could be??

Code:

```
DateTime startDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startDateTxt.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);
DateTime endDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(endDateTxt.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ta-IN").DateTimeFormat);
int smonth = startDate1.Month;
int day = endDate1.Day;
int emonth = endDate1.Month;


if (DateTime.Now.Month ==smonth && (emonth == DateTime.Now.Month +1 || emonth ==DateTime .Now .Month))
{
    if (endDate1 >= startDate1 && endDate1.Day <= 20)
    {
        string script = "alert(\"Possible\");";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be that we are missing your code. Without it we can only guess...